# Calculate the gradient of the map $(x_1,\ldots,x_m)\mapsto g(f_1(x_1),\ldots,f_m(x_m))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Calculate the gradient of the map $(x_1,\ldots,x_m)\mapsto g(f_1(x_1),\ldots,f_m(x_m))$ where $g\in C^1(\Bbb R^m,\Bbb R)$ and $f_k\in C^1(\Bbb R,\Bbb R)$.

I dont know exactly what to do in this exercise. My work so far: let define $$h:\Bbb R^m\to \Bbb R^m,\quad x:=(x_1,\ldots,x_m)\mapsto (f_1(x_1),\ldots,f_m(x_m))$$

We have also that $\partial h(x)=\sum_{k=1}^m\partial_k h(x)$ and $\partial_j h(x)=f'_j(x_j)e_j$ then

$$\partial(g\circ h)(x)=\partial g(h(x))\partial h(x)\\=\partial g\big(f_1(x_1),\ldots,f_m(x_m)\big)\big(f'_1(x_1),\ldots,f'_m(x_m)\big)\\=\Big(\nabla g\big(f_1(x_1),\ldots,f_m(x_m)\big)|\big(f'_1(x_1),\ldots,f'_m(x_m)\big)\Big)$$

I dont know if this can be simplified further. Some tip, or help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You could express $\nabla g$ as a vector of partials of $g$, but that's about it. Is this really all you want to ask or are you unsure about something?

Comment: @Git I just wanted to know if the expression is enough simple... that is, if there are some other symbolic expression simpler that what I had wrote, that is all.

Comment: You could write it as $\sum \limits_{k=1}^m\left(\partial _kg\color{blue}{(}f_k(x_k)\color{blue}{)}f'_k(x_k)\right)$, where $\partial_kg$ denotes the partial derivative of $g$ with respect to its $k^{\text{th}}$ variable, for all $k$ in $\{1, \ldots, m\}$.